# Add border to triangle element in css3

Tags: css, animation, geometry, border

This is my code

CSS

```
#page {
    width: 900px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    direction: rtl;
    position: relative;
}
#box1 {
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    box-shadow: -3px 8px 34px #808080;
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: -8px 5px 5px #888888;
    right: 300px;
    top: 250px;
    text-align: justify;
    -webkit-transition: all .75s;
    font-size: large;
    color: Black;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #D0D0D0;
    opacity: 0;
}
@-webkit-keyframes myFirst {
    0% {
        right: 300px;
        top: 160px;
        background: #D0D0D0;
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        background: #909090;
        :;
        right: 300px;
        top: 200px;
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
#littlebox1 {
    top: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
}
.littlebox1-sentence {
    font-size: large;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    background: #D0D0D0;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-transition: background .25s ease-in-out;
}
#bothcontainer:hover ~ #box1 {
    -webkit-transition: all 0s;
    background: #909090;
    :;
    right: 300px;
    top: 200px;
    -webkit-animation: myFirst .75s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: initial;
    opacity: 1;
}
#bothcontainer:hover .littlebox1-sentence {
    background: #909090
}
#bothcontainer:hover .triangle {
    border-right: 25px solid #909090
}
.triangle {
    position: relative;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-right: 25px solid #D0D0D0;
    border-top: 27px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 24px solid transparent;
    right: 184px;
    -webkit-transition: border-right .25s ease-in-out;
}
```

HTML

```
<body dir="rtl">
  <div id="page">
    <div id="bothcontainer">
        <div id="littlebox1" class="littlebox1-sentence">put your mouse here</div>
        <div id="littlebox1" class="triangle"></div>
    </div>
  <div id="box1"></div>
</div>
```

I want to add a border to the triangle, to `.littlebox1-sentence`.

The border will *not* change its color.

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gp43Q/)

---

I have come closer to finding the solution, but it still is not where I want it.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DyxA4/3/)

Comment: You have two divs with the same id. Not allowed. How about using the outline property! - div id="littlebox1

Comment: Hi, they the same id becouse only in this way the anumation will be in the both classes, I couldn't do it in different way. is it wrong?

Comment: You can't have same id's mate. Id's should be unique.

Comment: Ok, I will change this, thank yuo! but can you explain me how can I add a border to this thing?
(I am a student and just started learning rhis).

Comment: The only way I can think of is if you don't mind extra markup. As @AlienWebguy stated, because you have used the border property to make a triangle so it comes at the cost of not being able to give another border. However what I suggest is make another div, give it the same styles and use position absolute on it. It may work.

Comment: Or you could use box-shadow. Just thinking outside the box (pun intended)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution: skip the border-based triangle and use three divs instead:

```
<div class="sign">
    <div class="arrow"><div></div></div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
</div>
```

Basically, we use ".arrow div" to create the triangle, and ".arrow" the cut off the bits we don't need:

http://jsfiddle.net/k5J6M/1/

Answer (score 2):

I'm not exactly sure what effect you're after, but I'd have a look at -webkit-filter. It allows you to add a shadow to "this element and any children it has, regardless of shape".

```
#littlebox1 {
       top: 200px;
       position: absolute;
       display: inline-block;
       -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(green -10px 0 10px);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DyxA4/

Comment: That is well. But the HTML is fundamental flawed because of the same ID. He is looking to add a border (thinline) around the triangle. Unless he fixes that, any styles applied will be both to the triangle and the text.

Comment: Thank you very much. but as @Jawad said I am looking for a thin line around the triangle. I fixed the divs name (I hope so, you will find this here - http://jsfiddle.net/DyxA4/2/) , is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 1):

The triangle IS the border. You can't do what you're asking. Just make an image.

Comment: I know, and that is whay I need help, I haven't any problem to copy and change completly new code for the triangle. Any Idea how can I do it pleas?